# C# HTTP Web Service Method with Optional Parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

This project is a `HTTP WEB API`. I want to build an interface which users can post some information to the server.

The `finger_print_base64` is a integrant parameter, and `threshold` or `mini_matches` is selectable parameter.

I knew the way to set MessageName .

```
[WebMethod(MessageName = "Default")]
public void SearchPerson(String finger_print_base64)
{

}

[WebMethod(MessageName = "AddThreshold")]
public void SearchPerson(String finger_print_base64,int threshold)
{

}

[WebMethod(MessageName = "AddMinMatches")]
public void SearchPerson(String finger_print_base64,int mini_matches)
{

}
```

But It doesn't work. And I know why it is wrong.

Please tell me how to achieve this interface with optional parameters

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you tell what doesn't work? Is there an error of some kind?

Comment: error message "SearchPerson already hava an method with the same type of parameters "

Comment: My advise would be to Rename Your Methods to: SearchPersonThreshold and SearchPersonMiniMatch. Now you have two methods with the same fingerprint in the same class which is not allowed.

Comment: For optional parameter you have to achieve method overloading.

Answer (score 0):

Rename your Methods to :

```
[WebMethod(MessageName = "AddThreshold")]
public void SearchPersonTreshold(String finger_print_base64,int threshold)
{

}

[WebMethod(MessageName = "AddMinMatches")]
public void SearchPersonMiniMatches(String finger_print_base64,int mini_matches)
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks to your answer. But if I rename the method name. Users need to invoke the different URL. It seems like invoking two WebMethods.

Comment: That's right and logical, as they are invoking two different webmethods